# Issues with ionic 4 - Cannot find module '@angular/core/package.json'

Tags: angular, windows, ionic4

I try to checkout a working ionic 4 project code. This project code is working fine on a Mac, but when I try to run it on a windows 10 PC. I got this error message - Cannot find module '@angular/core/package.json'. I was able create a working ionic 4 project codes using sidemenu template, blank template and tab template from my windows 10 PC. But the working project code on a mac doesn't work on my windows 10 PC. Please help.

Comment: make sure you are using the correct version of angular CLI and node on your windows machine

Comment: when I run ng version - It shows I am running Angular CLI: 7.3.0 and Node: 8.12.0

Comment: and What's your Angular verison in Package.json file?

Comment: @angular/core "^7.2.2" @angular/common "^7.2.2" @angular/forms "^7.2.2" @angular/http "^7.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be fixed. When I issue the following command line
cd to my project path then do a

npm install